# How make frameless Chrome App Window movable?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I've created a Chrome app with a window but it's not movable. I want to make the top bar (HTML/CSS styled) what allows it to move. I looked at the Chrome App samples, but cannot find the code that makes dragging a window around possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I discovered the answer and it did not appear in the documentation, nor was it obvious. It is a CSS property that controls this.

```
-webkit-app-region: drag;
```

Without that, your frameless window is not moveable.

IMPORTANT: Any child node of the draggable node that you want to be clickable or interactable, needs a `-webkit-app-region: no-drag;` on its CSS.

For example:

```
.myCustomBar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
}

.myCustomBarCloseButton {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
}
```

Comment: It is documented on the create frame parameter. http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window.html#method-create

Comment: Even later on after a few months, this help a lot with just the simple explanation thanks Don

Comment: @VincentScheib This seems to be confusing a lot of people, maybe the documentation could be updated to show some sample CSS code showing this required setting?

Answer (score -1):

```
    Just add below code in your background.js

    chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
      chrome.app.window.create("frameless_window.html",
        {  frame: "none",
           id: "framelessWinID",
           innerBounds: {
             width: 360,
             height: 300,
             left: 600,
             minWidth: 220,
             minHeight: 220
          }
        }
      );
    })

And follow  https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/frameless-window
    Here you can find the best sample for creating frameless chrome app with the movable window.It's little bit confusing because, after installing it in chrome you can able to create its shortcut on the desktop as well.
```